# Entity being modified between controller and view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

How is this possible?
 [image: Controller]
[image: View]
[image: ViewCode]

Two days of headbanging. If anyone has a sane explanation, that would be nice.

Note that if I remove the `EditorFor(o => o.DocumentParentID)`, the value changes to 0 when received in the [HttpPost], so it them matches the other record of the DB

Note that these are the related records in the DB
[image]

Comment: The value of ID was 8 in the controller, but 6 in the view. No modifications were made, the view appeared like that in the browser

Comment: What happens when you change the 6 in the editor of the ID in the view to 15? Which property on your entity is changed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting value of 6 for ID property because it matches to the Id parameter in your route. It seems default model binder is also looking for those properties in your url.

Change parameter name for your action method or name of ID property in StatusClient class and it should work fine.

Also if you don't add `EditorFor(o => o.DocumentParentID)` in your view, DocumentParentID will not be posted back to your action method and you will get the default value 0.

Comment: Man that's brilliant guess ;)

Comment: That was it! You are a genius =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your asking, but I think it is why does ) default intto DocumentParentID when the EditorFor is not on the page?

The modelbinder will bind the default value of the object type so if you have defined the DocumentParentID as Int32, the modelbinder will bind to 0 on the post.  If the DocumentParentID is defined as Int32?, then the modelbinder will bind to null on the post.